# Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY == Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY

Tags: java, floating-point

I tried

```
System.out.println(Double.isInfinite(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY))
System.out.println(Double.isInfinite(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
```

and the output was

```
true
true
```

So this means "Infinity" is the same for both data types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and no.  Yes, because in an abstract sense infinity is infinity (and, as I explain below, for the purposes of most code floats are converted to doubles anyway).

No, however, because at the bit level the two infinities are different.  A double is 64 bits in Java, and a float is 32 bits in Java, so trivially they are different at the representation level.

In Java, floating-point numbers (floats and doubles) are represented using [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating-point format, which is the standard pretty much everyone uses nowadays.  Each number is represented in binary as a sign bit, plus a certain number of exponent bits, plus a certain number of mantissa (significand) bits.  In either a float or a double, positive infinity is represented with a sign bit of 0, exponent bits all 1, and mantissa bits all 0.  Negative infinity is represented the same way, except the sign bit is 1.  So infinity is represented in two very similar ways, but because of the differing counts of exponent and mantissa bits between floats and doubles, the bit-level patterns are different.

For the purposes of writing code, you can treat them as the same.  Whenever you use doubles and floats together, unless you explicitly say otherwise the float will automatically be cast to a double and the expression will result in a double, so a float infinity "acts like" a double infinity for most practical purposes.

Comment: I see. And the `Double.compare(double, double)` method would be smart (or, maybe dumb?) enough to return 0 for `Double.compare(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)` ?

Comment: @user1064918 This has nothing to do with `Double.compare(double, double)`.  As I allude to in my answer, wherever a double is expected and a float is supplied, the float is automatically cast to a double, so `Double.compare(double, double)` only sees two doubles.  The *JVM and hardware* are smart enough to recognize 32-bit infinity (float) and convert that to 64-bit infinity (double).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you happen to know what the binary presentation of NaN would be?

Comment: @user1064918 Sure.  In NaN, the exponent bits are all 1s, and the mantissa bits are *not* all 0s.  The sign bit can be either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "same". The bit patterns are different because the sign is different, but they're *still* both infinite.

In addition, the promotion rules for floats will preserve the infinite nature when converting to a double.

Comment: By 'same' I mean if you take the difference of the two, you'll get zero. I haven't checked what the bit patterns would be for both cases. But shouldn't they be the same, because that's what the Double.compare(...) method relies on?

Comment: @user1064918 No, the bit patterns aren't the same, because floats are 32 bits and doubles are 64 bits.  Furthermore, if you take the difference of the two, you'll get NaN, because Infinity - Infinity isn't a number in math either.

Comment: @user1064918: In fact, `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY - Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is also `NaN`, as is `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY + Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. Subtraction of two infinities simply isn't defined, regardless of which data type you use.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can't directly compare a `double` with a `float`.  Rather, when you attempt to do this, the `float` gets automatically converted to a `double` first.  The same thinng happens when you pass a `float` to a method that takes a `double` argument.  And when you convert `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` (for instance) to a `double` you get `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

So the answer to your question is that `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` are not entirely the same thing, but they both denote "a number that is too large to represent" and hence the answer that `==` gives you is logically consistent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to compare a `float` with `double` in Java as such. All the operations you are likely to use compare `double` with `double` after implcitly upcasting the `float` to a `double`

```
 float f= 
 double d =
 Double.compare(f, d);
 // equivelent to
 Double.compare((double) f, d);
```